# Split multiple values with header included into columns

Tags: t-sql

I have a column containing multiple values separated by a "," also including the headers separated by a ":".
The column looks like this:

```
{"Id":"c7d45d60-cf90-490d-be4c-f04c9349da03","RecordType":20,"CreationTime":"2018-06-12T21:48:30","Operation":"DownloadReport","OrganizationId":"dabd5d90-87c2-44c9-93cd-783e03236e40","UserType":0,"UserKey":"10033FFF85612C0C","Workload":"PowerBI","UserId":"xxxxxx@grundfos.com","ClientIP":"xxx.3.xx.111","UserAgent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/66.0.3359.181 Safari\/537.36","Activity":"DownloadReport","ItemName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","WorkSpaceName":"My Sales Dashboard testing environment","DatasetName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","ReportName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","CapacityId":"65CB790D-16C8-4DA6-BFA2-89854100423E","CapacityName":"Hope","WorkspaceId":"34812eed-830a-43b2-ae18-6c5c1c0c92a1","ObjectId":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","DatasetId":"b6184b73-fea2-4244-83ca-328e89c536af","ReportId":"36e6b6c5-ceeb-4d02-9d54-fb820634e839","IsSuccess":true,"DatapoolRefreshScheduleType":"None"}
```

Is there a way to split these values and their headers into separate columns?
So the first column would be named 'Id' and contain the value 'c7d45d60-cf90-490d-be4c-f04c9349da03' and so forth.
I have tried following the most upvoted solution to this similar question, but it doesn't seem to work:
[How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns#)

So I want to go from this:

[image]

To something like this:

[image]

I have tried to use this code, but it really doesn't work well:

```
SELECT [AuditData]
      ,Substring(AuditData, 1,Charindex(',', AuditData)-1) as Id
      ,Substring(AuditData, Charindex(',', AuditData)+1, LEN(AuditData)) as  RecordType
      ,Substring(AuditData, Charindex(',', AuditData)+2, LEN(AuditData)) as  CreationTime
  FROM [dbo].[Log]
```

Comment: Inlcude the code you've been trying that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I don't think I can use JSON functions? Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
 Jun  8 2018 18:18:54 
 Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: JSOn function are available in Azure. Have you tried @shnugo answer below?

Comment: Yes, and it seems to work. I just need to figure out how to pivot in the keys in as columns and the values as values in those columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing strange, just JSON. [Starting with version 2016 you can use `FROM OPENJSON()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) like here:

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(MAX)='{"Id":"c7d45d60-cf90-490d-be4c-f04c9349da03","RecordType":20,"CreationTime":"2018-06-12T21:48:30","Operation":"DownloadReport","OrganizationId":"dabd5d90-87c2-44c9-93cd-783e03236e40","UserType":0,"UserKey":"10033FFF85612C0C","Workload":"PowerBI","UserId":"xxxxxx@grundfos.com","ClientIP":"xxx.3.xx.111","UserAgent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/66.0.3359.181 Safari\/537.36","Activity":"DownloadReport","ItemName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","WorkSpaceName":"My Sales Dashboard testing environment","DatasetName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","ReportName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","CapacityId":"65CB790D-16C8-4DA6-BFA2-89854100423E","CapacityName":"Hope","WorkspaceId":"34812eed-830a-43b2-ae18-6c5c1c0c92a1","ObjectId":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","DatasetId":"b6184b73-fea2-4244-83ca-328e89c536af","ReportId":"36e6b6c5-ceeb-4d02-9d54-fb820634e839","IsSuccess":true,"DatapoolRefreshScheduleType":"None"}';
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@v);
```

The result

```
key            value                                 type
Id             c7d45d60-cf90-490d-be4c-f04c9349da03  1
RecordType     20                                    2
CreationTime   2018-06-12T21:48:30                   1
[... more rows ...]
```

### UPDATE get this as PIVOT list

There are two approaches:

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(MAX)='{"Id":"c7d45d60-cf90-490d-be4c-f04c9349da03","RecordType":20,"CreationTime":"2018-06-12T21:48:30","Operation":"DownloadReport","OrganizationId":"dabd5d90-87c2-44c9-93cd-783e03236e40","UserType":0,"UserKey":"10033FFF85612C0C","Workload":"PowerBI","UserId":"xxxxxx@grundfos.com","ClientIP":"xxx.3.xx.111","UserAgent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/66.0.3359.181 Safari\/537.36","Activity":"DownloadReport","ItemName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","WorkSpaceName":"My Sales Dashboard testing environment","DatasetName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","ReportName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","CapacityId":"65CB790D-16C8-4DA6-BFA2-89854100423E","CapacityName":"Hope","WorkspaceId":"34812eed-830a-43b2-ae18-6c5c1c0c92a1","ObjectId":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","DatasetId":"b6184b73-fea2-4244-83ca-328e89c536af","ReportId":"36e6b6c5-ceeb-4d02-9d54-fb820634e839","IsSuccess":true,"DatapoolRefreshScheduleType":"None"}';
```

--PIVOT

```
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT [value],[key]
    FROM OPENJSON(@v)
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(t.[value]) FOR t.[key] in(Id,RecordType,CreationTime)
) p;
```

--JSON_VALUE

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@v,'$.Id') AS Id
      ,JSON_VALUE(@v,'$.RecordType') AS RecordType
      ,JSON_VALUE(@v,'$.CreationTime') AS CreationTime
```

Try it out...

### UPDATE 2: Get this from a table

This is simple.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, yourJSON NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('{"Id":"blah1","RecordType":10]}')
                      ,('{"Id":"blah2","RecordType":20]}')
                      ,('{"Id":"blah3","RecordType":30]}');
SELECT t.ID 
      ,JSON_VALUE(t.yourJSON,'$.Id') AS JsonId
      ,JSON_VALUE(t.yourJSON,'$.RecordType') AS RecordType
FROM @tbl t;
```

### Hint

For your next question: Please do not paste pictures. Try to add a *reduced stand-alone running sample* ([so called MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) as I do it above. Oterwise people have to type this in for you.

Comment: This solution seems nice and simple, but how do I get the values in separate columns instead of row values in the key column?

Comment: @user2776167 If you know all Keys in advance you can use simple pivot.

Comment: I do and they shouldn't change over time. I'll look into pivoting the keys and values into columns. Any hints on how to do that? @Shnugo

Comment: That also works perfectly! Many thanks for writing such clear code!

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to do it for each row in the table instead of just one variable.

Comment: Many thanks again! You have been a great help and I found the answer based on your code. Also thanks for pointing out the MCVE etiquette. I can't give you any stars due to my low rank, but you can get an ASCII high-five ヘ( ^o^)ノ＼(^_^ )

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the data as mentioned in the comments above, then using the [Jeff Moden's splitter function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) you can use this approach

It's better to use separators that will not ever appear in the dataset

```
;WITH CteSpace AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@j,'"', ''),'{', ''), '}', '') , ',')
)
SELECT
    [Id]    = LEFT(Item, CHARINDEX(':', Item) - 1),
    [Value] = SUBSTRING(Item, CHARINDEX(':', Item) +1, LEN(Item) - CHARINDEX(':', Item))
FROM CteSpace
```

provides this output

```
Id                          Value
Id                          c7d45d60-cf90-490d-be4c-f04c9349da03
RecordType                  20
CreationTime                2018-06-12T21-48-30
Operation                   DownloadReport
OrganizationId              dabd5d90-87c2-44c9-93cd-783e03236e40
UserType                    0
UserKey                     10033FFF85612C0C
Workload                    PowerBI
UserId                      xxxxxx@grundfos.com
ClientIP                    xxx.3.xx.111
UserAgent                   Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML- like Gecko) Chrome\/66.0.3359.181 Safari\/537.36
Activity                    DownloadReport
ItemName                    My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018
WorkSpaceName               My Sales Dashboard testing environment
DatasetName                 My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018
ReportName                  My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018
CapacityId                  65CB790D-16C8-4DA6-BFA2-89854100423E
CapacityName                Hope
WorkspaceId                 34812eed-830a-43b2-ae18-6c5c1c0c92a1
ObjectId                    My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018
DatasetId                   b6184b73-fea2-4244-83ca-328e89c536af
ReportId                    36e6b6c5-ceeb-4d02-9d54-fb820634e839
IsSuccess                   true
DatapoolRefreshScheduleType None
```

Comment: Any string split approach will have to deal with the fact, that a separator, which occurs between qoutes is not a separator.  If there is the slightest chance, that one of the values contains a comma within the content (e.g. *ObjectId="My Salesresponsibility, Final 12-06-2018"*), this approach will break... This might pass any test but break in production...

Comment: That is true but if the OP doesn't have SQL 2016 then they can't use `OPENJSON` , this doesn't leave ,many other alternatives

Comment: True... You would have to run through the characters and watch for opening and closing quotes in order to replace embedded delimiters with another character which has to be re-set after the split. Possible, but heavy...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have SQL 2016 and want to use JSON string then you can use [Phil Factor's ParseJSON function](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/)

Then, as @Shnugo has mentioned, there's no need to worry about separators appearing in your dataset and breaking your code

```
DECLARE @j NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"Id":"c7d45d60-cf90-490d-be4c-f04c9349da03","RecordType":20,"CreationTime":"2018-06-12T21-48-30","Operation":"DownloadReport","OrganizationId":"dabd5d90-87c2-44c9-93cd-783e03236e40","UserType":0,"UserKey":"10033FFF85612C0C","Workload":"PowerBI","UserId":"xxxxxx@grundfos.com","ClientIP":"xxx.3.xx.111","UserAgent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML- like Gecko) Chrome\/66.0.3359.181 Safari\/537.36","Activity":"DownloadReport","ItemName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","WorkSpaceName":"My Sales Dashboard testing environment","DatasetName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","ReportName":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","CapacityId":"65CB790D-16C8-4DA6-BFA2-89854100423E","CapacityName":"Hope","WorkspaceId":"34812eed-830a-43b2-ae18-6c5c1c0c92a1","ObjectId":"My Salesresponsibility Final 12-06-2018","DatasetId":"b6184b73-fea2-4244-83ca-328e89c536af","ReportId":"36e6b6c5-ceeb-4d02-9d54-fb820634e839","IsSuccess":true,"DatapoolRefreshScheduleType":"None"}'


SELECT name, stringvalue
FROM dbo.parseJSON(@j)
```

Output

```
name            stringvalue
Id              c7d45d60-cf90-490d-be4c-f04c9349da03
RecordType      20
CreationTime    2018-06-12T21-48-30
Operation       DownloadReport
OrganizationId  dabd5d90-87c2-44c9-93cd-783e03236e40
UserType        0
UserKey         10033FFF85612C0C
```

Answer (score 0):

In a very roundabout way, I got the answer I needed. I made a new view containing the JSON from the column in the following way:

```
SELECT
        JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.Id') AS Id
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.RecordType') AS RecordType
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.CreationTime') AS CreationTime
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.Operation') AS Operation
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.OrganizationId') AS OrganizationId
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.UserType') AS UserType
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.UserKey') AS UserKey
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.Workload') AS Workload
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.UserId') AS UserId
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.ClientIP') AS ClientIP
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.UserAgent') AS UserAgent
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.Activity') AS Activity
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.ItemName') AS ItemName
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.WorkSpaceName') AS WorkSpaceName
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.DatasetName') AS DatasetName
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.ReportName') AS ReportName
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.CapacityId') AS CapacityId
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.CapacityName') AS CapacityName
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.WorkspaceId') AS WorkspaceId
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.ObjectId') AS ObjectId
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.DatasetId') AS DatasetId
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.ReportId') AS ReportId
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.IsSuccess') AS IsSuccess
        ,JSON_VALUE(AuditData,'$.DatapoolRefreshScheduleType') AS DatapoolRefreshScheduleType

FROM [dbo].[Audit_Log];
```

Many thanks to @Shnugo for helping out a newbie like me to Stackoverflow.